# Why doesn't CodeIgniter have an option to use $_SESSION?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, memcached

I'm using CodeIgniter for the first time, and I'd like to store sessions server-side in Memcache.

However, it seems like the only built-in option is to use a MySQL database table (`ci_sessions`). Is this true?

Why doesn't CodeIgniter offer the option to plug in to the session auto-global (`$_SESSION`) and then let you pick your storage engine? 
It seems this would be much easier than baking in their own solution.

If I was using Drupal or some other framework I could simply configure session storage in my PHP config file, but now it seems I need to add in a library or write something just to be able to use Memcache.

Comment: CI sessions more are flexible. But, you can extend default session class if you need.

Comment: Read this article http://www.moreofless.co.uk/using-native-php-sessions-with-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not wondering "How to do it", I'm asking if anyone knows a reason why they made this choice in the first place. I really don't understand what's so flexible about their approach.

Comment: Well I guess why cars have four wheels instead of five? (my opinion)